# Show that the $i$th local cohomology functor is zero for $i > 0$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, local-cohomology

Let $I$ be an ideal of a Noetherian ring $R$, and let $M$ be a module over $R$.  Let $\Gamma_I(M)$ be the set of all elements  $m$ of $M$ for which $I^n m = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$.  Then $\Gamma_I(-)$ is a left exact functor.  Let $H_I^i(-)$ denote the $i$th right derived functor of $\Gamma_I(-)$.  This is the *local cohomology functor.*

I'm trying to show that if $\overline{M}$ is the quotient module $M/\Gamma_I(M) = M/H_I^0(M)$, then $H_I^i(\overline{M}) \cong H_I^i(M)$ for $i > 0$.  I considered the long exact sequence $$\cdots \rightarrow H_I^0(\overline{M}) \rightarrow H_I^1(\Gamma_I(M)) \rightarrow H_I^1(M) \rightarrow H_I^1(\overline{M}) \rightarrow H_I^2(\Gamma_I(M)) \rightarrow \cdots $$ and tried to show that $H^i(\Gamma_I(M)) = 0$ for all $i > 0$.  That should do it.  This is equivalent to saying that if I take an injective resolution of $\Gamma_I(M)$ $$0 \rightarrow \Gamma_I(M) \rightarrow E^0 \rightarrow E^1 \rightarrow \cdots$$ and apply the functor $\Gamma_I(-)$: $$0 \rightarrow  \Gamma_I(E^0) \rightarrow \Gamma_I(E^1) \rightarrow \cdots$$ then this sequence remains exact at any $\Gamma_I(E^i), i > 0$.  Is this obvious?  I would appreciate a hint, not a full solution.

Comment: What you need to show that the $E^i$ for $\Gamma_I(M)$ are also $I$-torsion modules. Once you have this, then the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [**Corollary 2.1.7**](https://books.google.com/books?id=AlWRLlFMXeEC&q=Let+M+be+an+a-torsion+R-module#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book **Local Cohomology** by *Brodmann-Sharp*. In parts (i) and (ii) they have $H_I^i(\Gamma_I(M))=0, \forall i \gt 0.$ Now use your long exact sequence in the question.

Comment: How do you show that the injective resolution terms are $I$-torsion?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.**

1. If $E$ is an injective module, then $\Gamma_I(E)$ is also injective.
2. If $M$ is an $I$-torsion module, then there is an injective resolution of $M$ whose all terms are $I$-torsion.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I was able to show (1) using the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over Noetherian rings.